# Difference between NSWeekCalendarUnit and NSWeekDayCalendarUnit for UILocalNotification repeatInterva

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

What is the difference between NSWeekCalendarUnit and NSWeekDayCalendarUnit for UILocalNotification repeatInterval?

```
localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
NSDate *currDate1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"Default_AlarmTime"];
localNotification.fireDate = currDate1;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Alarm";
localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

How many times local notification is fired?

Answer (score 0):

If you set NSWeekdayCalendarUnit for repeatInterval property then it will be called daily.

If you set NSWeekCalendarUnit for repeatInterval property then it will be called weekly.